# What is the simplest way to compare two arrays in QUnit

Tags: javascript, arrays, exists, element, qunit

I'm writing JavaScript unit tests (with the QUnit library). I need to verify that my array contains expected (and only) elements.

```
var array = getArrayFunction(a, b);
equal(["one", "two", "three"], array, "Test is failing even if 'array' contains needed elements");
```

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use `deepEqual()` in lieu of `equal()`. That will compare array elements and object properties, not just use the `==` comparison operator, which evaluates to `false` for objects that don't share the same constructor.

Docs here: https://api.qunitjs.com/deepEqual/

More information about JavaScript equality comparison: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Comment: Glad that worked! Please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: In a minute :) (stackoverflow's requirement for 5 minutes delay before acceptance becomes possible)